# Идолы — истуканы

Tags: этимология

Меня заинтересовало слово "истукан". Сейчас оно носит несколько негативный характер — что-то бессмысленное, варварское. Но откуда такое слово, явно происходящее от "стук"? Это как-то связано с языческими обрядами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "идол, божок", др.-русск., цслав. истуканъ "вырезанный, высеченный", прич. прош. вр. страд. зал. от истукати "резать, лить из металла"; с др. вокализмом: тъкнѫти (см. ткнуть, ты́кать). Ср. греч. τύκος "резец", τυκίζω "высекать"

Фасмер. Так что этимология тут от способа производства истукана, а не использования.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен. К стуку прямого отношения не имеет. Корень, видимо, действительно общий, но на очень древнем уровне. Приставка "ис", а в "стуке" - "с". Хотя в современном языке возможно и не вычленять приставку в обоих случаях.